# Horizontalbar view height change when pull to refresh

Tags: ios, swift, pull-to-refresh

I have a tableview with a horizontalbarview in the tableviewcell. I add a pull to refresh action on the tableview and when i pull to refresh the height of the horizontalbar changes.

Before pull to refresh
[image]

After pull to refresh
[image]

Can anybody tell me how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: What is constraints of your horizontalbarview ?

Comment: I did add constraints on it. I set the frame for the horizontalbar. @mihatel

Comment: This sounds like the initial size of the bar was determined before autolayout was finished laying out its parent views, and the refresh happened after everything is layed out.

Comment: Can i fix this? @meggar

Comment: is the bar in a storyboard, or are you adding it in code?

Comment: The bar is in the storyboard but i set the frame in code. @mihatel

Comment: After autolayout is finished laying out the tableviewcell, it will call viewDidLayoutSubviews().  if you override that function you can check if the bar is the correct size, and then set the frame there if it is not.  make sure to  check if it is already the correct size or there could be an infinite loop.

Comment: it keeps the correct size al the time. But when i pull to refresh viewDidLayoutSubviews gave nothing back. Weird @meggar